# how to get access to current MessageActivity from PromptDialog choice in BotFramework

Tags: botframework

I'm presenting the user with 4 choices via the PromptDialog.choice method. In my Resume method, I want to forward the user to a dialog to handle their choices. I no longer have access to the current MessageActivity object
 and wonder what my options are? I'd like to pass the original Message if at all possible. Passing an empty one seems like a hack. And the dialog PrintGraphicDialog will just display a graphic image and return back to the 4 choices. using Context.Call hits the PrintGraphicDialog's StartAsync method and has the context.wait() call which requires the user to type something. Then it prints the graphic. Not quite what is wanted either.

```
private void ShowOptions(IDialogContext context)
{
    PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.OnOptionSelected, new List<string>() { OptionOne, OptionTwo, OptionThree, OptionFour }, "Please select from the following options:", "Not a valid option", 3);
}

private async Task OnOptionSelected(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
{
    try
    {
        string optionSelected = await result;

        switch (optionSelected)
        {
            case OptionOne:
                await context.Forward(new PrintGraphicDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog, context.MakeMessage(), CancellationToken.None);
                break;
            case OptionTwo:
                break;
            case OptionThree:
                break;
            case OptionFour:
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (TooManyAttemptsException ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the message in a variable right before calling your `PromptDialog.Choice` and then use it in the Resume method.

Comment: adding Private IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> _activity; and assigning it before calling PromptDialog works. But when I await it to pass it to the new dialog, its always null. var message = await _activity; message is null. In the new dialog and before calling it.

Comment: Try storing the IMessageActivity and not the IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> meaning, do an await before storing it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the dialog I was forwarding control to really only needs a few properties from the original message, I just created a class, stored them in there and before forwarding, did context.MakeMessage() and populated that with the stored off properties. Seems like there should be a better way.